# What are these weird line breaks?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why my text is breaking in weird places. There is no CSS that affects the wrap or display. I have narrowed it down to the below code causing the issues. (See HTML and CSS). I am pretty sure that the intro-serv div text is breaking because it is wrapping around part of the banner-text container, but not sure how to get around it. Once again - thank you for any and all assistance.

(Sample image here: http://disposablewebpage.com/turn/ecoifEp5N0 this is a screenshot of dreamweaver)

Here is my code:

```css
div#banner-text {
  background-color: rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.6);
  color: black;
  color: #black !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.45em !important;
  font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
  float: right;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 470px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  word-spacing: 0em;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

p.p-serv {
  background-color: pink;
}

div.bodyContent {
  width: 968px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 24px auto 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

div.mainContentSingle {
  padding: 20px 44px 44px 44px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d3d4;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #2B2727;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  background-image: url('../img/BackgroundMain_02.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  line-height: 20px;
  "

}

div#intro-serv {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<link href="./HP Indigo 10,000 Press   Superior Packaging &amp; Finishing_files/new_product_services.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bodyContent">

  <!-- Main body content -->

  <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cpMainBody_pnlMainContent" class="mainContentSingle">

    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cpMainBody_cpMainContent_CmsContentDiv" class="page-content page-content-3413">
      <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cpMainBody_cpMainContent_pageTitle" class="SubHeader" style="color:#80888E;font-size:20px;">HP Indigo 10,000 Press Provides You With Color, Sheet Size, and Substrate Options for Hundreds of Applications</span>

      <!--   //*-----------------------begin content that I can edit--------------------------*//-->


      <!--BEGIN  STYLE TO HIDE HEADER TEXT FROM PAGE-->
      <style>
        span#ctl00_ctl00_cpMainBody_cpMainContent_pageTitle.SubHeader {
          display: none;
        }
      </style>

      <!--END  STYLE TO HIDE HEADER TEXT FROM PAGE-->

      <div class="breadcrumb"><a href="http://www.superiorpackagingandfinishing.com/">Home</a> &gt;
        <a href="http://www.superiorpackagingandfinishing.com/pages/about-us">Full Services</a></div>

      <div class="container"> <img src="./HP Indigo 10,000 Press   Superior Packaging &amp; Finishing_files/hp-indigo-10-000-printing.jpg" alt="HP Indigo 10,000 Press" title="HP Indigo 10,000 Press" style="" class="primary-image" />

        <!--BEGIN  BANNER TEXT HTML-->

        <div id="banner-text">Banner Text
        </div>

        <!--END BANNER TEXT HTML-->

        <!--BEGIN INTRO HTML-->

        <div id="intro-serv">intro Bacon ipsum dolor amet cillum turducken lorem deserunt, beef ribs venison mollit. Veniam deserunt cupim fatback capicola, ut chuck jowl kielbasa ribeye jerky cow sint lorem pastrami. Kielbasa flank non beef porchetta. Brisket laboris ullamco
          excepteur sirloin ham hock qui meatloaf spare ribs short ribs</div>

        <!--END INTRO HTML-->

        <!--BEGIN STANDARD BODY HTML-->

        <p class="p-serv">You probably need everything from marketing materials, like business cards and brochures, to in-house forms and training publications like seminar workbooks. With the variety of printed materials, comes a variety of quantity, color, and substrate
          requirements. Our HP Indigo 10,000 can handle them all.</p>


        <!--   //*---------------END content that I can edit--------------------------------*//-->

        <div class="Clear"></div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>

        <!-- /Main body content -->

        </body>

        </html>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question.

Comment: Possibly a float blocking part of the div, but impossible to tell without code.

Comment: Also, a link to a jsfiddle is always preferable to a link to a live site.

Comment: The link provided doesn't even is a live site, but just a screen capture of one.

Comment: above code works fine.[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zolacexonu/1/edit?html,output). please provide link to your site or post a complete code. is it a wordpress site?

Comment: Do you have a <pre> tag encapsulating the <div>? or the CSS style "white-space: pre;" to any parent?

Comment: no <pre> anywhere in the code. there is white-space style in CSS but all of it refers to tooltip items "no-wrap" and didn't not solve issue when deleted.

Comment: also forgot to say no this is not wordpress

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r20e688p/  based on pared down code

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the text in a `<p>text goes here</p>`.  I've found that it can assist with formatting issues like this.  Of course, I don't feel like I know the whole story without extra code to see what else could be affecting it.

Comment: That's a lot of code to pour through.  It's likely that something in all that code is causing this.  You may have to pare back the code to just the elements affecting this text to get a better feel for the issue.  Otherwise, with this much code we may be shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the banner text div was causing the intro-serv div to line break due some sort of floating.

I added

```
margin-bottom: -100px;
```

to the

div#banner-text {

properties and it solved the line break problem.  Full updated code below:

HTML: same as original

**CSS:**

```
div#banner-text {
    background-color: rgba(218,218,218, 0.6);    color: black;
    color: #black !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2.45em !important;
    font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
    float: right;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    width: 470px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    word-spacing: 0em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

Thank you to all who responded.